# Website not opening in Chrome?

Tags: browser, google-chrome

One of my friend's site's users getting this error.

**Oops! This link appears to be broken in Google Chrome**

http://www.labnol.org/software/webpages-not-opening-in-google-chrome/13041/

Can he do something with their hosting to ensure users of his site will not get this error.

Comment: Knowing the URL of the page where the problem happens could help find out the cause of problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As it is a browser bug, you cannot change this behaviour.

well: as the bug only occurs if prefetching links from your page fails, you could of course remove all 'href' attributes from your html-source and add them on page load using javascript. this would end in chrome not fetching up anything: no fetching => no fetching error. but this 'solution' is not practical.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using redirects? Cause chrome wants a status header with that.